# Best way to only perform a function if a (.NET) DLL is loaded?

Tags: c#, dll

I am not sure the best way to explain this so please leave comments if you do not understand.

Basically, I have a few libraries for various tasks to work with different programs - notification is just one example.

Now, I am building a new program, and I want it to be as lightweight as possible. Whilst I would like to include my notification engine, I do not think many people would actually use its functionality, so, I would rather not include it by default - just as an optional download.

How would I program this?

With unmanaged Dlls and [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services), I can basically wrap the whole lot in a try/catch loop, but I am not sure about the managed version.

So far, the best way I can think of is to check if the DLL file exists upon startup then set a field bool or similar, and every time I would like a notification to be fired, I could do an if/check the bool and fire...

I have seen from the debug window that DLL files are only loaded as they are needed. The program would obviously compile as all components will be visible to the project, but would it run on the end users machine without the DLL?

More importantly, is there a better way of doing this?

I would ideally like to have nothing about notifications in my application and somehow have it so that if the DLL file is downloaded, it adds this functionality externally. It really is not the end of the world to have a few extra bytes calling `notification("blabla");` (or similar), but I am thinking a lot further down the line when I have much bigger intentions and just want to know best practices for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

> I do not think many people would
>   actually use its functionality, so, I
>   would rather not include it by default
>   - just as an optional download.

Such things are typically described as plugins (or add-ons, or extensions).

Since .NET 4, the standard way to do that is with the [Managed Exensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com). It is included in the framework as the `System.ComponentModel.Composition` assembly and namespace. To get started, it is best to read the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx) and the [MEF programming guide](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guide).

Comment: I have only recently (last two months) got in to serious c# development, There were talks about MEF at a usergroup I am a member of... I just wish I was in to serious programming back then as it completely went over my head - I had no idea that this is what it was about... After writing the question, I suddenly had a thought about how to write a middleman type extension that would work the way I want... However, I will certainly take a look at MEF to see if it does what I need first (If it isn't to complicated... I'm still quite new!)

Answer (score 2):

You can use System.Reflection.Assembly and its LoadFile method to dynamically load a DLL. You can then use the methods in Assembly to get Classes, types etc. embedded in the DLL and call them.

If you just check if the .dll exists or load every .dll in a plugin directory you can get what you want.

Comment: Subtle distinction, but you can also test whether Load succeeds, without knowing the path.  Assembly binding configuration can be used to control e.g. the location of a plugin directory without the program needing to know how name resolution works.  In other words, the code should be agnostic about the actual physical assembly file.

Comment: I will take a look at the System.Reflection.Assembly - Thanks.... ...edited whitespace in to your answer as it says I have already voted and won't let me up vote... I think related to the outage earlier.

Answer (score 1):

To your question if the program will run on the user's machine without the dlls already being present - yes , the program would run. As long as you dont do something that needs the runtime to load the classes defined in the dll , it does not matter if the dll is missing from the machine. To the aspect you are looking for regarding loading the dll on demand , I think you are well of using some sort of a configuration and Reflection ( either directly or by some IoC strategy. )

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the plugin at startup.

Instead of checking a boolean all over the place, you can create a delegate field for the notification and initialize it to a no-op function.  If loading the plugin succeeds, assign the delegate to the plugin implementation.  Then everywhere the event occurs can just call the delegate, without worrying about the fact that the plugin might or might not be available.